# Cometd with glassfish

Tags: glassfish, comet, cometd

I have been trying tp get cometd http://cometd.org/ to work with glassfish server, but I couldn't run the chat sample, seems I'm missing some libraries

I found this in the glassish documentation
http://docs.sun.com/app/docs/doc/820-4496/ggrgt?a=view
But this doesn't give much, no subscribe and publish as found in Cometd example with Jetty, just long polling

If I'm using cometd, must I use jetty server ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you had any luck with this in the last 6 month, but I came across the following:

[http://developers.sun.com/appserver/reference/techart/cometslideshow.html](http://SUN%20Comet%20SlideShow)

Exract:

1. To use Comet with GlassFish, add the bold red line to the GlassFish domain.xml file in the glassfish-v2ur2\domains\domain1\config directory:

   ```
   <http-listener acceptor-threads="1" address="0.0.0.0"
       blocking-enabled="false" default-virtual-server="server"
       enabled="true" family="inet" id="http-listener-1" port="8080"
       security-enabled="false" server-name="" xpowered-by="true">
       **<property name="cometSupport" value="true"/>**
   </http-listener>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

I am running `CometD` successfully on a GlassFish Server. You must not add the property "cometSupport" to the server (otherwise it will not work).

On the project [website](http://cometd.org/) you will find a complete documentation. Moreover, I suggesto to check out this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/web/library/wa-reverseajax4/?ca=drs-) which also includes an example.

Comment: how do you make it work, when i try to enable comet on GlassFish with this command 'asadmin set server-config.network-config.protocols.protocol.http-1.http.comet-support-enabled="true"' always outputs 'Command set failed.'

Comment: @Shikatsu Please ask a new question instead of resurrecting old ones.